# how do i propeply reference microsoft ASPNETCORE Identity in my project for visual studio code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to extend Identity user class in my project so that I can customize it to fit my application
the problem I am having is that it telling me that IdentityUser class could not be found

when I try to extend it, as shown below, I get an error saying " The type or namespace name 'IdentityUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
    {

      public ApplicationUser()
      {

      }
    }
```

I thought adding the package to my .csproj file was enough as shown below

```
dotnet add AtlasBooking.Storing/AtlasBooking.Storing.csproj package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
```

but I still run into the same problem even after adding it. Please how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't referenced the correct namespace. Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;` to the code file.

Comment: What version of .Net Core?

Comment: it's netcoreapp3.0